# Whitelisting Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-security-group

I have a server in AWS, which is hosting a security tool. Azure DevOps supports this tool and I've installed the add on for it. I've added the step to my Pipeline and configured the service connection.

We are using Hosted Agents in a Cloud AZD instance.

When I run my pipeline, I get the following error:

```
##[error][TOOL] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"1.1.1.1","port":443}
```

In my AWS security group, I have allowed the Inbound IP's for Azure DevOps listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions

I have also allowed the Geographical IP's for listed in the json file here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

If I allow all traffic for 443 through the security group as a test, this works as expected. This is not a solution however as this is a security tool and should not be public.

In my pipeline, I added a task to run a curl command to inspect the IP's of the pipeline. Neither of these ranges appear in any list I can find published.

```
51.142.72.0/24
51.142.229.0/24
```

I was advised to post here by AzureDevOps on Twitter for some help, so hopefully someone can assist me here.